# Adding a range to an existing list using a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm wanting to use `AddRange` to add a list of items to an existing list, rather than iterating. My question is, if the collection I have added to my existing list is a lambda expression, will it be re-evaluated when I access my existing list or essentially the items added to my existing list at that point.
If the former then I could of course simply evaluate the expression by using `.ToList()`. see below:

```
_divisionsInGroup.AddRange(Event.Divisions.Where(x => x.SplitGroup == SplitGroup));
```

**OR DO I NEED**

```
_divisionsInGroup.AddRange(Event.Divisions.Where(x => x.SplitGroup == SplitGroup).ToList());
```

**EDIT:**
It appears to evaluate the expression and add the items to the list, so no need for creating a new list instance by calling ToList() on the lambda.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because try it and find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to call ToList() on the lambda, the expression is evaluated by the AddRange method and the items are appended to the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

`AddRange` changes the underlying List object.

`_divisionsInGroup.AddRange(Event.Divisions.Where(x => x.SplitGroup == SplitGroup));`

will change the `_divisionsInGroup`.

`.ToList())` should be used if you want to further convert it into `List<T>`.